# Generating all permutations excluding cyclic rotations in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a (practice) program for currency arbitrage that detects profitable "loops" given a series of exchange rates.  So there might be different values for USD->JPY, JPY->USD, USD->EUR, and so on.  In order to detect profitability, however, I first need to enumerate all possible loops -- USD->JPY->EUR->USD is one example, but USD->EUR->JPY->USD is a distinct example using the same currencies since it may hit different exchange rates.

If I ignore the last part of the loop, which will always be the same as the origin, it seems to be the case that every currency can only exist at most once in the "best" loop, as if a currency exists more than once it would actually be two different loops (at least one of which would still be profitable).

Similarly, I can ignore loops that are just translations of already tested loops: USD->JPY->ASD is the same as JPY->ASD->USD.

So, given input like *[USD,JPY,EUR,ASD]* I need something that would return:

```
(USD,JPY,EUR,ASD)
(USD,JPY,ASD,EUR)
(USD,EUR,ASD,JPY)
(USD,EUR,JPY,ASD)
(USD,ASD,EUR,JPY)
(USD,ASD,JPY,EUR)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the yield from syntax introduced in Python 3.3.  Like the built-in itertools.permutations(), this:

- Is a generator and does not require storing anything
- Will yield an empty tuple if passed length 0
- Assumes every item in the permuted object is itself unique

```
from itertools import permutations
def unique_cyclic_permutations(thing, length):
    if length == 0:
        yield (); return
    for x in permutations(thing[1:], length - 1):
        yield (thing[0],) + x
    if length < len(thing):
        yield from unique_cyclic_permutations(thing[1:], length)
```

The algorithm works by choosing a pivot, fixing it at the beginning, and then permuting the rest of the objects.  In the case of a non-full length permutation, there will also be some permutations that don't include the pivot object at all.  In this case, the generator recursively calls itself while excluding the original pivot.